# reveal more than one image - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This piece i am creating is a comic.

the comic images will be hidden until a user clicks the mouse

the hope is that the images will then reveal them self one at a time (per users click)

at the moment however when one image is shown it will dissapear when the user clicks to show the next image

how can i set it up so that the image doesnt dissapear when the user clicks?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        color: red;
        background-color: #1F2A22;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #00ff00;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <img id="fans6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="fans6.png">
    <img id="impact6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="impact6.png">
    <img id="text6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text6.png">
    <img id="panel7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel7.png">
    <img id="atom7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="atom7.png">
    <img id="fantext7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text fan7.png">
    <img id="text7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text7.png">
    <img id="fans7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="fans7.png">
    <img id="panel8"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel8.png">
    <img id="bang8"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="bang8.png">
    <img id="panel9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel9.png">
    <img id="reporter9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="reporter9.png">
    <img id="text9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text9.png">
    <img id="panel10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel10.png">
    <img id="full10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel full10.png">
    <img id="text10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text10.png">
    <img id="end10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="the end10.png">

    <script>

    var curImage = 0;
    var images = ["fans6","impact6","text6"];

    function windowClick() {
        document.getElementById(images[curImage]).style.opacity = "0";
        if(curImage < images.length - 1)
        {

            document.getElementById(images[0]).style.opacity = "1";
            curImage = 0;
        }
    }




    window.onclick = windowClick;

    </script>





    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By removing this line

```
        document.getElementById(images[curImage]).style.opacity = "0";
```

The image won't disappear when a user clicks.

But i guess you should modify your code a little (I don't think current version will work the way you want it to work)

```
 function windowClick() {
        if(curImage < images.length - 1)
        {
            document.getElementById(images[curImage]).style.opacity = "1";
            curImage++;
        }
    }
```

Because every time you should increment the `curImage` and then display the image with index `curImage` to show the next image.

Comment: yes you are right the image does nothing now. it is already revealed. i am trying to have the opacity of each image to 0 and when the user clicks the opacity is up to 100. and as mentioned it will show one image per user click

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to script problems [pointed out by void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647836/reveal-more-than-one-image-javascript/28647901#28647901), it seems all of your images lie on top of each other due to same absolute position and size, so that one of them will occlude all others.

Comment: the images arent in the same location on my screen, they are all in different locations. see image "http://s18.postimg.org/guijlnpx5/image.png"  also this video will give you an idea of what i am trying "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whza8AbiT9U"

Comment: Maybe they're all covering the same overall area, but are transparent in different parts of that area?